# What smoothing parameter makes sense for a LOESS calibration curve?

Tags: logistic, smoothing, calibration, loess

I am creating a [calibration curve](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/14/calibration-plots-in-sas.html) to asses the fit of a logistic regression.

**Does it make more sense to use the local or global optimum smoothing parameter for the LOESS line?**

[image]

The orange line uses the global optimum smoothing parameter, the blue line uses the global optimum. Both are types optimum parameter values determined algorithmically.

The global optimum looks nicer, but I worry that I am over-smoothing and would be unable to detect actual model miscalibration. The local optimum (orange) has the opposite problem - I may be including too much noise, making the calibration curve useless.

Note: For SAS users, the LOESS statement in PROC SGPLOT uses the global optimum by default. Whereas, the PROC LOESS uses the local optimum smoothing parameter by default.